# BIRT: Query a MongoDB array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, birt

I'm new to BIRT and I was wondering how i can access only one data of a MongoDB array. For now i can only specify a field and the field i want is in an array, so it gives me all the values for this field in an array. e.g.: `[val1, val2, val3]`

The problem is I only want one value to show because I want other fields form the same array.
i.e.: 
`COLUMN1            COLUMN2            COLUMN3
element[0].field1   element[0].field2  element[0].field3
element[1].field1   element[1].field2  element[1].field3
element[2].field1   element[2].field2  element[2].field3`

and now it's giving me

`COLUMN1
[element[0].field1, element[1].field1, element[2].field1]`

and so on for the other columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it. It was in the `Advanced settings` from the `Query` section in the `Data sets` section..

[image: Flatten nested collections]